# Page not loading when using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, function

When this function is ran, `results.php` does not get loaded. I have tested to see if the function itself is even called, and it is (as "hello1" gets alerted). However, for some reason, the contents of results.php are not getting loaded into the correct section.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadTable(){
    alert("hello1");
    $("#results_page").load("results.php");
}
</script>
<div id="results_page"></div>
```

Here are the contents of `results.php`. (I used an `alert("Hello2")` to check if it gets loaded, and hello2 does not get alerted so I am assuming the page does not get loaded.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello2");
</script>
</html>
```

It thus seems the issue lies with the following statement in `wedding.php` (the original document)

```
$("#results_page").load("results.php");
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

`loadTable()` gets called in a seperate function which too is loaded. Here is a more detailed version of what the main program (`wedding.php`) looks like.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#form_details").load('form.php');
});
function loadTable(){
    alert($("#results_page").length);
    $("#results_page").load("results.php");
}

</script>
<div id="form_details"></div>
<div id="results_page"></div>
```

So upon execution, `form.php` gets loaded. This file contains a form which gets filled in. Once the form is submitted, a function called `load()` gets called which calls `loadTable().`
Here is what `form.php` looks like.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
    alert("hello");
    loadTable();
}
```

`form.php` also contains a form, however to keep things concise I have not included it.

When testing, hello gets alerted, and therefore i believe `load()` is correctly executed. Hello1 also gets alerted, and therefore i believe `loadTable()` is correctly executed

Comment: I have made some edits

Comment: From the code that you pasted, it seems that loadTable is not invoked at all. You will need to invoke loadTable in jquery's document.ready.

Comment: Replace your hello1 alert with `alert($("#results_page").length)` (or console.log and look in the browser console).  It will be 0.  Your code is running before the element exists.  Call your code after your div defer running by putting it in doc ready `$(function() { loadTable() }` (this assumes it's being called at all, as per other comment, but you say it is, it's just not in the code you've provided).

Comment: "*so I am assuming the page does not get loaded*" - personally, I would assume that scripts aren't run when using `$().load()` (I'm not sure if they are/aren't).  Replace your alert hello2 with `<h1>included</h1>` and look in the browser network tab to see what's going on.

Comment: I cant put it in the doc.ready function though as that function can only be called once a form has been filled in (the results page loads a table that relies on inputs from a form)

Comment: I tried <h1>included</h1> and it does not get displayed

Comment: I also replaced alert("hello1") with the alert($("#results_page").length) and it alerted 1.

Comment: Maybe include in the question where/when/how you call loadTable() so we're not left speculating...

Comment: A big update was made containing more detail.

Comment: Have you guys seen the update made?

Comment: Does it work if you (temporarily) remove `$("#form_details").load('form.php');`?  Does it work if you replace load formphp with `$("#results_page").load("results.php");` (in the doc ready).  Do you get any errors in the console / network tab?

Comment: You know: 1) $.load works as it works in your form.php  2) your call to loadTable works 3) the placeholder / destination exists.  What's the other variable?  4) `results.php` - so check that loads ok (see previous comment) - if that works ok, then it's something between loading form.php and loading results.php.

Comment: Yes when i replace "form_details".load('form.php') which .load('results.php'), it works.

Comment: Like you said it must then be an issue between `form.php` getting laoded and `results.php` getting loaded. What could this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Try #2.

I have created what I think is a replica.  Three html pages.

main.html - On page load, loads form.html

form.html - Click the button and it calls main.html function loadResult()

result.html - has the result info

main.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadResult(){
        console.log("loading result");
        $("#resultPage").load("result.html");
    }

    function loadForm(){
        console.log("loading form");
        $("#formPage").load("form.html");
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadForm();
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>

<div id="formPage"></div>

<div id="resultPage"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

form.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        console.log("calling loadResult on main page");
        loadResult();
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>FORM PAGE</h1>

<form onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

result.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("inside result page");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>RESULT PAGE</h1>
<i>The Result</i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No this replica is incorrect. I have the `main.php` which automatically loads form.php upon startup (doc.ready). Then, when the form is submitted (on `form.php`), a function is loaded (`load()`) (on `form.php`) which calls another function (`loadTable()`)(on `main.php`) which then loads `results.php`

Comment: Do you understand the structure of my program?

Comment: However the issue is when `loadTable` (or `loadResult`) gets called, the alert message works, however the `results.php` does not get loaded.

Comment: However the issue is when `loadTable` (or `loadResult`) gets called, the alert message works, however the `results.php` does not get loaded.

Comment: If you check the comments under the main post, @freedomn-m seemed to get somewhere with identifying where the issue lies.

Comment: Can you load the results.php by itself?  To make sure it compiles and shows the results you're expecting.

Comment: yes i have loaded it and it shows the results i am expecting

Comment: Are all three pages running on the same web server?  Making sure it's not a CORS issue.  You would see that error in the browser console log.  Any errors in the console log?

Comment: Have you still got any ideas?

Comment: Can't think of anything.  I tried boiling it down to the least common denominator with the html I posted.  It shows the idea will work.

Comment: Is there another way I can get `results.php` to run when the the form on `form.php` is submitted? I need this to be the case because `results.php` creates a table based on the inputs from `form.php`

Comment: I think I may have it.  Change your form submission to return false so it doesn't reload the page.  I modified the form.html page with the code.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear it.

Comment: And this is why we have so much difficulty - there's no mention of a `<form>` or event how `loadTable()` gets called (despite numerous requests) other than *"loadTable() gets called in a seperate function"* - which doesn't imply it's being called from a form `submit`.  Some very simple debugging in the browser looking at the network tab would show what's going on and that the main page was being reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

add run of function loadTable() like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadTable(){
     alert("hello1");
     $("#results_page").load("results.php");
  }
</script>
<div id="results_page"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  loadTable();
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

file: index.php:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadTable(){
         alert("hello1");
         $("#results_page").load("results.php");
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
         loadTable();
      });        
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results_page"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

file results.php:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello2");
</script>
</html>
```

All worked fine.

alert("hell1") -> alerted

alert("hello2") -> alerted

Comment: I can't do this because loadTable() gets called in another file (which too is loaded into the main program (wedding.php).

Comment: I beleieve the function is called correctly as alert("hello1") still gets alerted

Comment: @DanielDavis What is the event that triggers loadTable in wedding.php? could you show us that code?

Comment: What is index.php?